# A standard loop for reading from a text file C++

Tags: c++, file, error-handling, eof

I'm learning about how to work with files in C++ and as a beginner I've got some doubts that I would like to clarify :

In my book the author introduces the stream states and writes this simple piece of code to show how to read until we reach end of file or a terminator :

```
// somewhere make ist throw if it goes bad : 
void fill_vector(istream& ist, vector<int>& v, char terminator)
{
    ist.exceptions(ist.exceptions() | ios_base::badbit); 

    for (int i; ist >> i;) v.push_back(i); 
    if (ist.eof()) return; // fine: we found end of file 

    // not good() not bad() and not eof(), it must be fail()
    ist.clear(); 

    char c; 
    ist >> c; // read a character, hopefully terminator

    if (c != terminator) {  // not the terminator, so we must fail
        ist.unget();        // maybe my caller can use that character 
        ist.clear(ios_base::failbit); 
    }
}
```

This was a first example, which provides a useful method to read data, but I'm having some issues with the second example where the author says :

> Often, we want to check our read as we go along, this is the general strategy assuming that `ist` is an 'istream':

```
for (My_type var; ist >> var;) { // read until end of file 
    // maybe check that var is valid 
    // do something with var

}

if (ist.fail()) {
    ist.clear(); 
    char ch; 
    // the error function is created into the book : 
    if (!(ist >> ch && ch == '|')) error("Bad termination of input\n"); 

}
// carry on : we found end of file or terminator
```

> If we don't want to accept a terminator-that is, to accept only the end o file as the end- we simply delete the test before the call of error().

**Here's my doubt** : In the first example we basically check for every possible state of the istream to be sure that the reading terminated as we wanted to, and that's ok. But I have problems in understanding the second example :

1. What does the author means when he says to remove the test before the call of error ?

   2. Is it possible to avoid triggering both eof and fail when reading ? If yes, how ?

I'm really confused and I can't understand the example because from the test that I've done the failbit will always be set after eofbit,  so what's the sense of checking for failbit if It will always be triggered? Why is the author doing that

Answer (score 1):

> What would happen to the code if I remove the test before the call of error as the author says ? Wouldn't that be useless as I would only be checking for the bad state of the stream ?

I think I see what you mean. No, it's not really useless, because you would tell someone (I don't know what `error` actually does), the programmer (exception) or the user (standard output), that the data had some invalid data, and someone has to act accordingly.

It may be useless, but that depends on what you want the function to do, if for example you want it to just silently ignore the error and use the correct data already processed, it really *is* useless.

> How can I read data from a file until I just reach the end of that file without using any other terminator ?

I can't see what you mean, you are already doing that in both examples:

```
if (ist.eof()) return; // fine: we found end of file
```

and

```
if (ist.fail()) { //If 'ist' didn't fail (reaching eof is not a failure), just skip 'if'
```

Comment: I think I'm still confused, I've tried to test again the second example to see what happens If I decide to throw an exception with `error()` in case of `fail`, the problem is that when I reach the end of file I get both `fail` and `eof` as stream state of `ist`. I've tried this example by reading 10 integers from a file until `eof`.

Comment: @PieroBorrelli are you sure, because according to the [docs](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ios/fail), `eof` is not a failure. Maybe there was an invalid character (white space?) at the end?

Comment: After trying with other examples I noticed that you're right and that I had a file terminating with a whitespace. Now If I try to read a file without any invalid character at the end I get eof(), when does eof get triggered exactly ? When I reach the last value of a file right ?

Comment: That's because I've read some other questions where they say that eof is triggered when I try to read after reaching the end.